# makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: iphone, integer, pointers

i have a simply warning in my iphone dev code.

```
NSUInteger *startIndex = 20;
```

This code work, but i have a warning :

warning: passing argument 1 of 'setStartIndex:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning pretty much says it all: you are initialising `startIndex`, which is a *pointer* to `NSUInteger`, to `20`, which is an integer literal. You need to allocate the space to hold the integer itself somewhere.

It *may* be that what you want is something more like this:

```
NSUInteger *startIndex = malloc(sizeof(NSUInteger));
*startIndex = 20;
```

Or perhaps

```
static NSUInteger startIndex = 20;
NSUInteger *startIndexPtr = &startIndex;
```

But given the var name, it seems you may also be muddling the semantics a bit, and probably really just want:

```
NSUInteger startIndex = 20;
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUInteger is a scalar type (defined as `typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;`). Correct your code to:

```
NSUInteger startIndex = 20;
```

You can use it directly afterwards (or with &startIndex if you need to pass a pointer to NSUInteger).